# I am unable to do anything with my select field in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

This is the code. I am not able to see any changes on my select. Neither append nor empty is seen here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert("Button click");
            $("#myselect").empty();
            alert("Done");
            $("#myselect").append('<option value="3">3</option>');
        });
   };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="intro">Hello World!</p>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button>Empty the Selector</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include jQuery to make it works. Also, you're missing `)` to close your DOM ready handler

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#myselect").empty();
        alert("Done");
        $("#myselect").append('<option value="3">3</option>');
    });
}); // <-- here
</script>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y245P/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I had updated the older code. Can you kindly take a look at the newer script and let me know your opinion.

Comment: OMG. I am so sorry. Such a trivial mistake. Thank you so much.